# Kotlin Emulator does not run app when as use a png image as drawable

Tags: android, kotlin, drawable

I'm using `Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1` and Pixel 5 API emulator.

The following code is used to show image in a button.

But when I use `calc.png` emulator says launch is successful but quit from application.

If I use xml image as source it works fine.

```kotlin
Icon(imageVector = ImageVector.vectorResource(
   id = R.drawable.calc),
   modifier = Modifier.size(buttonWidth),
   contentDescription = "drawable icons",
   tint = Color.Unspecified
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When painter has been used it is worked.

```
        Icon(
                    painter = painterResource(R.drawable.calc),
                    modifier = Modifier.size(buttonWidth),
                    contentDescription = "drawable icons",
                    tint = Color.Unspecified
                )
```